# Htc m7 facebook unable to connect and other apps don't show thumbnails

Tags: google-play-store, google, htc-one

have a weird problem with my htc m7 , i can't open facebook from the apps or even the browser ?!!!
and google play and and drive don't show thumbnails
The other problem is with calls ,i can't hear my callers and neither can they *
help please

Comment: Provide more details. OS version. Rooted or not, when the issue began and just before the beginning of this issue, what have you done. And what have you done so far.

Comment: Can you receive SMS?

Comment: yes i do receive Sms

Comment: I'm under android 4.4.1 , the phone is not rooted , and i bought the phone this way i don't have much informations about when it began